# grep not working as expected

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Given a file, "test.log" with the following contents:

```
line1 Patient 123 45566
line2 Patient 432
line3 Patient 234 456
line4 Patient 321
line5
```

I am trying to select `line 2` and `line 4` with this pattern:

```
grep "Patient\s\d+\s" test.log
# but this works testing at https://rubular.com/
```

Doesn't work nor does this:

```
grep "Patient\s\d+\n" test.log
# but this works testing at https://regexr.com/47qd5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rublar does Ruby regular expressions. Regexr does JS REs or PCRE.  `grep` does POSIX basic or extended regular expressions, or PCRE if you're using GNU `grep` and the `-P` option.  What `grep` are you using (are you on Linux)?

Comment: Also, are there spaces after the numbers on line 2 and 4? Your first expression seem to want to match these...

Comment: `grep -V; grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` also tried with `grep (GNU grep) 2.27`

Comment: @Kusalananda it's a log file so there shouldn't be. my example is truncated

Comment: `Patient\s\d+[^\s]$`

Answer (score 6):

#### 1. Use either named classes or PCRE

GNU `grep` uses by default Basic Regular Expressions (BRE), but it also let you use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) and Perl-compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE).

Please note that neither BRE nor ERE support `\s` nor `\d`, but they have similar features. From `man grep`:

> Finally, certain named classes of characters are predefined within bracket expressions, as follows. Their names are self explanatory, and they are `[:alnum:]`, `[:alpha:]`, `[:cntrl:]`, `[:digit:]`, `[:graph:]`, `[:lower:]`, `[:print:]`, `[:punct:]`, `[:space:]`, `[:upper:]`, and `[:xdigit:]`. For example, `[[:alnum:]]` means the  character class of numbers and letters in the current locale. In the C locale and ASCII character set encoding, this is the same as `[0-9A-Za-z]`. (Note that the brackets  in these  class names are part of the symbolic names, and must be included in addition to the brackets delimiting the bracket  expression.) Most meta-characters lose their special meaning inside bracket expressions. To include a literal `]` place it first in the list. Similarly, to include a literal `^` place it anywhere but first. Finally, to include a literal `-` place it last.

Example:

```
$ grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+$' << 'EOF'
> foo
> 123
> bar
> EOF
123
```

You may also use PCRE, as it supports `\s` and `\d`:

```
$ grep -P '^\d+$' << 'EOF'
> foo
> 123
> bar
> EOF
123
```

#### 2. `\n` doesn't work

In Unix every `\n` delimits a *line*. `grep` prints *lines* that match a given pattern. Matching `\n` itself wouldn't make sense in this context.

You could either use `$` to match the end of the line:

```
$ grep -E 'foo bar$' << 'EOF'
> foo
> foo bar
> foo bar baz
> EOF
foo bar
```

or pass the `-z`/`--null-data` option to activate the "multiline" mode (you'll need some extra workarounds to exactly match what you want):

```
$ grep -Poz '(?<=\n)?foo bar\n' << 'EOF'
> foo
> foo bar
> foo bar baz
> EOF
foo bar
```

#### 3. Your first example doesn't do what you think

That last `\s` will match `line 1` and `line 3` instead of `line 2` and `line 4`:

```
$ grep -P 'Patient\s\d+\s' << 'EOF'
> line1 Patient 123 45566
> line2 Patient 432
> line3 Patient 234 456
> line4 Patient 321
> line5
> EOF
line1 Patient 123 45566
line3 Patient 234 456
```

Comment: GNU `grep`'s BREs and EREs do support `\s` (not `\d` yet AFAIK). Neither are POSIX BRE/ERE.

Comment: What's the `(?<=\n)?` for?

Comment: `-z` is to work on NUL-delimited records instead of NL-delimited records. It's a bit misleading to call it the _multiline mode_. `pcregrep` has a `-M` option for a _real_ multiline mode.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-P` switch with GNU grep for Perl regular expressions and your syntax will work as you have it.

```
$ grep -V | head -n1
grep (GNU grep) 2.25

$ grep --help | grep "\-P"
  -P, --perl-regexp       PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901171/is-d-not-supported-by-greps-basic-expressions) for more information.

Comment: this doesn't work in my case

Comment: it works after I installed a newer version of grep which supports `-P` thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all regular expressions are using the same symbols, as others have already pointed out.  If you are on a system where the default `grep` implementation is not GNU `grep`, then you have POSIX regular expressions, and these don't use Perl-like patterns like `\s`.

You seem to want to `grep` for lines ending with a single positive integer (as opposed to zero or more than one integer).  Seeing your data, another way to formulate this is that you'd like to extract all lines with exactly three whitespace-delimited fields.

This is easy with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF == 3' test.log
line2 Patient 432
line4 Patient 321
```

`NF` is the number of fields (columns) in the current record (line), and with only a lone condition line this, the default action is to print all lines that fulfil the condition.

With `grep`, and with a more complete pattern that exactly specifies what we're expecting:

```
$ grep -Ex '[[:alnum:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+ [[:digit:]]+' test.log
line2 Patient 432
line4 Patient 321
```

The `-E` enables extended regular expressions (because we use the extended `+` modifier), and `-x` causes `grep` to match across a complete line.

`[[:alnum:]]+` matches letters and numbers (according to your locale), while `[[:alpha:]]+` and `[[:digit:]]+` matches letters and strings of digits respectively.

Another way of writing the same thing that uses ASCII ranges (disregards your locale setting):

```
grep -Ex '[A-Za-z0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+' test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of grep I was running on `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` on my outdated MacOS does not support `-P` so I installed 3.3 with `brew install grep --with-default-names` and then I was able to get this to work with:

```
grep -P 'Patient\s\d+$' test.log
```