# Shellscript match regex

Tags: shell, scripting, regular-expression

I am trying to check if a variable matches a regex in POSIX shell. However, this seems more difficult than I thought. I am trying to check if the variable is a valid size string (e.g. 10M or 6G etc)

```
if echo $var | grep -Eq '^\d+[MG]$';
then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "no match"
fi
```

That's what I tried, but for some reason I never get a match, even if the variable contains the correct string? Any idea why?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Alright. It told me to add doublequotes, however, the problem remains. Will use shellcheck from now on tho

Comment: Related: [grep not working as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498925/grep-not-working-as-expected) and [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GNU `grep` supports three types of regular expressions: Basic, Extended (ERE) and Perl (PCRE). In GNU `grep`, EREs don't provide functionality over basic ones, but some characters have special meanings, such as the plus sign. Source: man page.

`\d` does not mean anything special in an ERE; it's just the character `d`. To express digits, use `[[:digit:]]` or the old `[0-9]` (I wonder if there are character encodings where `[0-9]` is not the same as `[[:digit:]]`).

Your expression works as a PCRE, though:

```
if echo $var | grep -Pq '^\d+[MG]$';
then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "no match"
fi
```

Note the `-P` option instead of `-E`.

It would seem that POSIX `grep` [does not support PCREs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html). I have not read the POSIX ERE definition, though.

Comment: [Does every country use Arabic numerals?](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/5im7ts/does_every_country_use_arabic_numerals/). I wonder if there are character encodings where `[0-9]` is not the same as `[0123456789]`

Comment: Ironically, I guess Arabic countries don't, or they do plus they use their own fonts.